# WPF DataGrid ObservableCollection Binding - 5 rows with empty collection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm trying to bind an ObservableCollection to my DataGrid.  The collection is empty, yet the DataGrid shows 5 empty rows.  Any ideas as to what would cause this?

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" Name="dgBills" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10, 10, 10, 5" Background="DarkRed" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Bills}">

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding NextDueDate}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Desc" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Frequency" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Frequency}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: Is collection `Bills` being initialized with empty rows? Another point - try seeting the CanUserAddRows property to false on data grid.

Comment: Yea the Bills collection is instantiated but empty no code to add anything as of yet.  Initially i loaded 1 transaction into it on startup for testing but 5 rows appeared.  Took that code out...5 rows appear.

Comment: Also tried the CanUserAddRows didn't fix it.  I know that's for the empty row on the bottom to let the user manually insert a new row but I will not have that! Haha...

Comment: Why AutoGenerateColumns is set as true when you are defining the DataGridTextColumn explicitly?

Comment: It was the answer to a similar question which did not change it.  It's set to false at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I added C#

```
dgBills.ItemsSource = Bills;
```

And whala that fixed it.

[image]